# ¿Cómo hago para obtener un solo campo de un documento en Firebase?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase

No he encontrado en la documentación oficial acerca de obtener un solo dato de un documento, sin traer todo el documento, ejemplo si tengo un documento:

```
{
  nombre:"jose",
  apellido:"juarez",
  nacionalidad:"Mexicana"
  edad: 19
}
```

y quiero obtener la edad, sin traer los demás datos, estoy usando JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como tal en firebase (Firestore) no existe una forma para obtener sólo un dato de un documento, firebase siempre regresa los documentos completos.